# git commit return error

Tags: git, github

I  made an edit and I want to push it to my git repository after adding a file through`git add` and then running `git commit -m "commit msg"`.

However, it returns the following error:

`.git/hooks/commit-msg: 2: .git/hooks/commit-msg: Syntax error: newline unexpected.`

Why?

Comment: Hi @Ram, could you please provide the full error backtrace? Did you install any custom git hook?

Comment: it is the complete error yes i have even commited previously some files

Comment: Do you have the same issue also on other projects or it is related only to the project you are editing?

Comment: no actually I have two git init one in my loocalhost to a open source and one in my home with git remote set to my account when i try to access my account it gives the above error

Comment: Those two links can be useful? [Documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html)  and [Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gerrit-issues/1I8A6b8XZCI)

Comment: Can you also put the result of `$ cat .git/hooks/commit-msg` and specify your OS?

Comment: yes and even worked once with both of them

Comment: I am presently on ubuntu os on running cat it givs no such fileor directory but it gets manually opened by gedit

Comment: It looks like if your commit-msg hook got corrupted with an unexpected newline.  In order to prove this, launch `git commit -m "commit message" --no-validation` (check [this docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#commit-msg) for refs). This should skip the commit-msg hook